# r filtering a dataframe by a column contating a keyword

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to filter a column which contains a keyword (in this example dog) but I am having problems.

```
id <- c(1,2,3,4)
type <- c("dog1","dog2" ,"cat1","cat2")

df1 <- data.frame(id,type)
df1


dfdog <- subset(packagesall, type %in% c("dog"))
dfdog
```

I would be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `grep`:

```
df1[grep("dog",df1$type),]
```

Comment: also, note that the use of `subset` is generally discouraged in favor of `[` syntax. there are cases where `subset` can snag you.

Comment: not "generally." interactive use of subset, such as here, is perfectly fine. special cases such as loops or within functions, discouraged, yes.

Comment: I'm not sure new folks will get that nuance and many, many folks start interactively with something that eventually turns into a bona fide script and, perhaps, even grows into a function or get tossed into a loop. Just trying to help folks head off possible frustration later on.

Comment: should avoid using `$` in that case. It's just shorthand for `[[` afterall

Comment: That's not in the context of non-standard evaluation, tho (which was were I was coming from). ref: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#subset